# Do matching contributions under SIMPLE IRA apply to IRS 93-27 and 2001-43 distributions

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, retirement-plan, simple-ira

A SIMPLE IRA is set up which includes 3% matching contributions.

An employee receives money through payments which are under IRS 93-27 and 2001-43 guidelines. The payments are sort of like owning stock in the company.

Do the rules for SIMPLE require/restrict/allow matching contributions to be made upon these payments.

Comment: Matching to what? I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the two portions of your question. You're being compensated as a fund manager, and you have a SIMPLE IRA - what exactly matching you're talking about?

Comment: Are you considered self-employed, or are you a regular employee of this business?

Comment: Regular employee.

Comment: @littleadv The SIMPLE IRA requires the employer to match elective deferrals up to 3% of compensation.  I think the question is whether the money received in the second paragraph counts as compensation for computing the 3% requirement. (Alternatively under simple, the employer could make nonelective contributions, but I gather that's not what's happening here based on the question.)

Comment: I wonder: Once you are receiving profit from your partnership profit interest, are you now considered self-employed?  This is a great question, by the way.  +1.

Comment: @BenMiller I think you nailed it. Partner != employee.

Comment: @Brick Right, asking if that other money will also be matched. I looked at this too much and can only assume I'm an employee

Comment: @FullDecent I didn't follow why the others thought you weren't an employee, but I don't recognize and didn't look up the IRS guidelines that you listed either. I would think that if you get a W-2 then you are an employee. That doesn't necessarily preclude also getting some income through an ownership share (reported on a 1099 or a Sch K). No idea how that works into the SIMPLE IRA rules though, which is why I haven't posted an answer.